# TypeScript and RequireJS - where'd my static typing go?

Tags: requirejs, typescript

In TypeScript, I can use RequireJS to import modules:

```
import Foo = require("common/Foo"); // Foo is one of my TypeScript exported classes.

class Bar {

   // Wooohooo! I can use Foo here, complete with intellisense!
   new Foo(1, "ab").zanzibar();
}
```

But sometimes I don't want to load Foo until it's really needed, like once some function is called:

```
class Bar {

   doSomething() {
      // OK, now we need Foo. Import it.
      require(["common/Foo"], Foo => {
          // Use Foo here.
          // Uh oh. No intellisense -- where did my static typing disappear to?
          new Foo(1, "ab").zanzibar(); // Works at runtime, but no intellisense. :-(
      });
   }
}
```

Is there a way to tell TypeScript what type Foo is?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Modules in TypeScript documentation](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript&referringTitle=TypeScript%20Documentation) (see "Optional Module Loading"):

#### Sample: Dynamic Module Loading in require.js

```
declare var require;
import Zip = require('./ZipCodeValidator');
if (needZipValidation) {
    require(['./ZipCodeValidator'], (x: typeof Zip) => {
        if (x.isAcceptable('...')) { /* ... */ }
    });
}
```